# PHP not running in CRON but does in Terminal

Tags: php, cron

Ok so if I run this in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/tasks/CreateContacts.php
```

The PHP script runs fine:

I have added this to `crontab -e`

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/tasks/CreateContacts.php > /root/CronTasks/CreateContact_Output.txt
```

It seems to be running ok because `CreateContact_Output.txt` has been created yet contains nothing - and my outcome changes (in database) haven’t been done.

This is running on an Ubuntu server.

**EDIT:** Added contents of PHP file below:

```
<?php
include '../public_html/_dbconnect.php';
include '../public_html/_functions.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails;";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0){
        //Do fuck all
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      $HeartID = CreateHeartContact($row['Name']);
      echo 'Sending Customer ID:' . $row['id'] . '<br>';
      $UniqueID = $row['id'];
      $NewQuery = "UPDATE CustomerDetails SET ID = '$HeartID' WHERE ID = '$UniqueID';";
      mysqli_query($con, $NewQuery);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Post CreateContacts.php. Are you relying on $_SERVER variables in your code to complete your task? This could be the problem. running `/usr/bin/php` by command, and by CRON will set completely different $_SERVER contents/keys.

Comment: It was the problem I had before, not sure if it's affecting you here too. But worth mentioning.

Comment: Not using `$_SERVER` in my code or called functions.

Comment: First of all, check your php error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should change to the working directory before running PHP, so that your `include` statement work :

```
*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/tasks/ && /usr/bin/php CreateContacts.php > /root/CronTasks/CreateContact_Output.txt
```

or you could use an absolute path as well in your code :

```
include realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/../public_html/_dbconnect.php';
```

Comment: This was great I use the code in the top line so my includes now work. I don't suppose you would be able to help me on why the logging just overrides rather than appends to the log? It seems to overwrite it each times it runs. Thoughts?

Comment: Just replace `>` with `>>` and it will append the output instead of rewriting it each time